# JPA: querying FK

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm using EclipseLink(JPA 2.0) under Netbeans 7.0 with JDK 7. Adding more, this is a JavaSE.

I have this tables, Employee and Record where in the relation is Employee(1) --- (*)Records.
Adding more about the structure of the Record: RecordID (PK), EmployeeID(FK), Status, etc.

I wanted to query out from the Record Table (not using the Employee->Rental Collection) what records has a relation with the employee..

I tried using the query, it always returns an exception

```
Exception Description: Error compiling the query [SELECT r FROM Record r WHERE 
r.employeeid = :employeeid], unknown state or association field 
[employeeid] of class [Record].
```

Answer (score 1):

From the information given it's not completely clear, but I believe you need to reference the id inside the Employee object.

eg. the correct query is probably:

`SELECT r FROM Record r WHERE r.employee.id = :employeeid`

(notice the extra dot in employee.id)

If this doesn't work, please provide us with some actual code of your Java classes.

Comment: It didn't work... I'll try to simplify the structure to be posted here... Sorry for the late response.